# How to pattern-match an overlapping set of characters? (using regex and grep)

Tags: regex, grep, pattern-matching, overlapping

say we have

```
1: ..FAF..FAF..
2: ..FAF.......
3: ..FAFAF.....
```

I need to pattern-match a triplet that occurs at least 2 times in a string, for example line 1&3 (the dots are placed to make it readable, they are actually characters `[A-Z]`).

I have only the solution for line 1

```
egrep '([A-Z]{3,}).*\1'
```

PS this is a simplified version of my text file

PPS it has to be with grep

**UPDATE**

I think I found the answer:

```
egrep '([A-Z]{3}).*\1|([A-Z])([A-Z])\1\2\1'
```

Comment: does it have to be mirrored? or ok to match `test..test` and `testest`

Comment: it's ok to match `testest` and `test..test`

Comment: sounds like you want lookahead, but posix regexes don't support that.

Comment: that's an exercise I've got at uni

Comment: sorry, my mistake.. it has to be a triplet, so test won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my trial pattern

```
(\b[A-Z]([A-Z]{2,})\2\b|\b([A-Z]{3,})\b.*\3)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/25)

Comment: for some reason I can't test it

Comment: this is what I'm trying `cat test | egrep '(\b[A-Z]([A-Z]{2,})\2\b|\b([A-Z]{3,})\b.*\3)'`

Comment: the reason it didn't work is because I had `X`-s instead of dots

Comment: would you edit your question and provide more examples

Comment: I think I found the answer. Thx for the idea.